# Add database connection inside asynctask Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to add a database connection inside my asynctask. This the code I'm working on:

DailySync.class:

```
DownloadSupplierMaster objAsyncTask;

// TODO get all checked items
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.daily_synchronize);

    initControls();

    objAsyncTask = new DownloadSupplierMaster(this);     

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dailysync_menu, menu);

        final MenuItem itemSync;

        itemSync = menu.findItem(R.id.sync);


        itemSync.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {


                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("Selected modules are...\n");

                ArrayList<SyncDataItems> itemList = dataAdapter.itemList;

                for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
                 SyncDataItems itemName = itemList.get(i);

                 if (itemName.isSelected()) {
                  responseText.append("\n" + itemName.getItem() );
                 }
                }


                objAsyncTask.execute();


                return true;
            }
        });


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result) {


}
```

DownloadTask.class:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Activity activity;
private AsyncTaskListener callback;

public DownloadSupplierMaster(Activity act) {
 this.activity = act;
 this.callback = (AsyncTaskListener)act;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

}

protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
    String result = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);

    try {
        JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String[] keys = { SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERCODE, SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERNAME, 
                SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERGROUP, SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERTYPE, 
                SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERADDRESS, SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERADDRESSALT, SupplierMaster.TAG_PHONE1, 
                SupplierMaster.TAG_PHONE2, SupplierMaster.TAG_FAX,
                SupplierMaster.TAG_EMAIL, SupplierMaster.TAG_WEBSITE, 
                SupplierMaster.TAG_EXPENSEACCOUNT, SupplierMaster.TAG_CONTACTPERSON,
                SupplierMaster.TAG_CREDITLIMIT, SupplierMaster.TAG_TOTALCREDIT, SupplierMaster.TAG_TIN,
                SupplierMaster.TAG_TAXCODE, SupplierMaster.TAG_TERMS };

        for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++) {    

            jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(i);

            for (String key : keys) {
                map.put(key, jb.getString(key));
            }
            arraylist.add(map);

            String suppliercode = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERCODE);
            String suppliername = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERNAME);
            String suppliergroup = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERGROUP);
            String suppliertype = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERTYPE);
            String supplieraddress = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERADDRESS);
            String supplieraddressalt = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_SUPPLIERADDRESSALT);
            String phone1 = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_PHONE1);
            String phone2 = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_PHONE2);
            String fax = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_FAX);
            String email = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_EMAIL);
            String website = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_WEBSITE);
            String expenseaccount = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_EXPENSEACCOUNT);
            String contactperson = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_CONTACTPERSON);
            String creditlimit = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_CREDITLIMIT);
            String totalcredit = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_TOTALCREDIT);
            String tin = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_TIN);
            String taxcode = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_TAXCODE);
            String terms = jb.getString(SupplierMaster.TAG_TERMS);

            context.dbConnect();   // I'M GETTING A NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION IN THIS LINE!!!!!!!!!!!!

            dbHelper.insertORReplaceToSUPPLIERCARD(suppliercode, suppliername, suppliergroup, 
                    suppliertype, supplieraddress, supplieraddressalt, phone1, 
                    phone2, fax, email, website, expenseaccount, contactperson, 
                    creditlimit, totalcredit, tin, taxcode, terms);

            dbHelper.close();

        }




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
} 

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    callback.onTaskComplete("Test");
}
```

AysncTaskListener.class:

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener {
     public void onTaskComplete(String result);
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting a nullpointerexception in context.dbConnect();

What do you think is the problem? Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you initialize context?

Comment: I was also looking for that.. I dont see where you initialize it, that might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Where is this context object coming from? Can you confirm that it has a value?

From a design perspective, I suggest creating a database helper class that is a singleton, that you can then access from the AsyncTask and let it handle the database interactions for the whole application as this will both be easier to handle these sorts of exceptions as well as make it very easy to maintain all the database related code for your app.